# $_REQUEST always empty after sending FormData through XHR

Tags: javascript, php, form-data

I am trying to use the FormData object to send a series of fields, both file and non-file, to a PHP endpoint on my server. However, no matter what I've done, the `$_REQUEST` superglobal is always blank within the PHP endpoint. The code I'm using to send the FormData is below.

```
const formData = new FormData();

formData.append('token', this.props.token);
formData.append('id', this.props.id);
formData.append('name', this.props.name);
formData.append('imageFile', this.props.image);
formData.append('entryFile', this.props.file);
formData.append('license', this.props.license);

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', 'https://path/to/endpoint', true);
xhr.send(formData);
```

Comment: Check the browser's debug console / network. Did the request leave with the data you expect?

Comment: @Scovetta Am I supposed to be able to see POSTed data in the debugger? Because I don't see any parameters at all.

Comment: In the request, after the headers, you should see the body of the request.

Comment: Nope, nothing after Accept-Language. One thing I didn't notice until now -- the request is tagged in the debugger as an OPTIONS request. Hope that helps.

Comment: @procrastinator Nothing in the address bar other than my localhost server and the hash link I'm putting in there.

Comment: @procrastinator Sorry, can you be more specific about exactly what you want me to do and what information you want? I'm not following. When the alert fires, I can't copy-paste anything.

Comment: Turn off async (set the third parameter in the `open` call to `false`) and see what comes back from `send(formData)`.

Comment: @Scovetta As far as the request, it's still a 403 from my server due to the token parameter not being sent. The return value of `xhr.send(formData)` is undefined. Were those what you meant by "see what comes back"?

Comment: @procrastinator I've set Access-Control-Allow-Origin to *. The request is being received correctly by my server, but none of the FormData's parameters are.

Comment: @procrastinator I see the alert and the address is just my local server address. If I copy it, I see the same thing. There's no redirect happening here.

Comment: @procrastinator Yes, I see the same webpage as in the other window.

Comment: Yes, the endpoint is functioning correctly, and returns a JSON object indicating a lack of permissions (due to the absence of the token parameter).

Comment: Try to use `let` or `var`.

Comment: I mean, currently your question is not detailed enough. Since there is nothing wrong with the address itself, and since the code is executing correctly, I suspect "Access-Control-Allow-Origin to *" and "lack of permissions" to be the part of the root cause but you don't say anything about it. Update your question please.

Comment: @procrastinator If that were a problem, I would be getting a Javascript error, not a valid response object from my endpoint. I didn't include it in the question because I don't believe it to be relevant in any way.

Comment: Everything is relevant in such a situation. Remember that we (the readers) are blind as long as your software is not publicly accessible :-) By the way, why do you think you would get a js error ? I mean, if you ask a question I guess you need some help, hence I think it's a little early to make this kind of assumption.

Answer (score 0):

You might need something like

```
xhr.open('POST', 'https://path/to/endpoint', true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhr.send(formData);
```